# How can I pass map<string,string> into py with API?

Tags: c++, python, c, api, cpython

C/C++ can use python API to load py.

But, only simple type is supported.

How can I pass map into py to be a dict with API?

Or, which methods are better?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/extending/

Comment: From Boost.Python, an example using map_indexing_suite (cppf file: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/test/map_indexing_suite.cpp and python file: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/python/test/map_indexing_suite.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python C API supports C-level functionality (not C++ level one) -- basically, you can easily expose to Python things you could put in an `extern C` block (which doesn't include `std::map` &c) -- for other stuff, you need a bit more work.  The nature of that work depends on what you're using to wrap your C++ code for Python consumption -- there are many options, including the bare C API, SWIG, SIP, Boost Python, Cython, ...

In the bare C API (which I assume is what you're using, judging from your question and tags), I would recommend [making a custom object type](http://docs.python.org/c-api/objimpl.html) -- maybe, these days, one subclassing [collections.Mapping](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#abcs-abstract-base-classes) (`MutableMapping` if mutable, of course), as you would when implementing a mapping in Python -- and implementing the [Mapping Object Structures](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#mapping-object-structures) plus the needed bits of a general [type structure](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#mapping-object-structures) such as `tp_iter` and `tp_iternext` slots.

Of course, the key idea is that you'll implement item setting and getting, as well as iteration, by simply delegating to your chosen `std::map` and performing the needed type conversion and low-level fiddling (object allocation, reference counting) -- the latter is the part that higher-level frameworks for extending Python save you from having to do, essentially, but the "wrap and delegate" underlying architecture won't change by much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which has [some ready-made templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html) for various STL types. [See this](http://realmike.org/python/extending_python.htm), for example.